# What does this webserver log entry tell me?

Tags: web-server

I am troubleshooting a system failure that occurred this morning and found these log entries shortly prior. In my mind these should be returning 404... right? Should I be concerned?

```
80.82.76.76 - - [13/Aug/2021:09:20:15 -0400] "GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 569
80.82.76.76 - - [13/Aug/2021:09:37:12 -0400] "GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1" 200 569
```

How would I reproduce this with cURL or postman? When I just put in a browser `http://mydomain/http://azenv.net/` it shows in the log with a `/` at the start. Also it goes to https and does not show in my http log.

Comment: Although this might be part of a pentest, this looks like a normal, non-pentest, webserver config question.

Comment: This is a proxy request, It can be reproduced by setting your web server as a proxy in curl. If these entries should return 404 or not depends on your specific (and unknown) server configuration and if the domain is your domain or not (also unknown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this resource which explains this issue thoroughly:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/ProxyAbuse

I was able to see what result the attacker was seeing by running

```
telnet mydomain.com 80
GET http://azenv.net/ HTTP/1.1
Host: azenv.net
[press enter twice]
```

My server just returned the default homepage rather than data loaded from azenv.net. This is the reason for the 200 status code. No vulnerability was exploited. The above resource explains how you could change this behaviour if wanted.